# Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction when i try to break my query to add conditional statement symfony 2 .8

Tags: symfony, dql, knppaginator

pls help i get this error

> Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction
>    when i try to break my query to add conditional statement

i have read this
KnpPaginatorBundle/Resources/doc/manual_counting.md and i arrived at this

```
    public function findCategoryProduct($category,$minPrice=null,$maxPrice=null,$gender=null)
              {
                  $countgb = $this->createQueryBuilder('1')
              ->select('count(p)')
                  ->from('AppBundle:Product','p')
                 ->join('p.group', 'g')
                ->join('g.category', 'c')
               ->where('c = :category')
               ->andWhere('p.visible >= :true')
               ->setParameter('category', $category)
              ->setParameter('true', 1);
               $count = $countgb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
              $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('1')
            ->select('p')
            ->from('AppBundle:Product','p')
            ->join('p.group', 'g')
            ->join('g.category', 'c')
            ->where('c = :category')
            ->andWhere('p.visible >= :true')
            ->setParameter('category', $category)
            ->setParameter('true', 1);
        $query ->getQuery()
            ->setHint('knp_paginator.count', $count);
        return $query;
    }

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query,$request->query->getInt('page', 1),10,array('distinct' => false));
```

and i still  get the error

Answer (score 0):

Hi I advise you to use subquery like :

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM CmsUser u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.phonenumber FROM CmsPhonenumber p WHERE p.user = u.id)');
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

or with expr:

```
$query->andWhere($query->expr()->notIn('c.id', $subquery->getDQL()));
```

some documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)